# Como transformar um system out para string?

Tags: java, android, textview

Quero exibir uma mensagem na tela do device.

A mensagem esta em `System.out.println("Mensagem ")`;

como faço pra transformar em uma `string` e imprimir na tela usando um `textView`?

Comment: Ou eu não entendi o problema ou isso não faz sentido. Seria melhor [edit] a pergunta com seu código real e mostrar o que deseja. Veja como fazer um [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Veja se isto ajuda.

```
 String mensagem = "Mensagem";

 TextView texto = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.id_do_texto_no_layout);

 texto.setText(mensagem);
```

Para "printar" na tela do android, nós utilizamos um `textview` no layout.xml da `activity`. Vc está tentando colocar na tela do android um texto escrito "Mensagem", mas em formato de string.
A última linha `texto.setText(mensagem);` é basicamente a mesma linha `System.out.println("Mensagem ");` porém para exibir no android.

Comment: Explique um pouco mais sobre como seu código ajuda a responder a pergunta

Comment: Para "printar" na tela do android, nós utilizamos um `textview`. Pelo que eu entendi da dúvida, ele está tentando colocar na tela do android um texto escrito "Mensagem", mas em formato de string.

Comment: A última linha `texto.setText(mensagem);` é basicamente a mesma linha `System.out.println("Mensagem ");` porém para exibir no android.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt, insira essas informações na sua resposta, quanto mais completa a resposta melhor avaliada ela será :D

Comment: Feito! Acredito que tenha ficado melhor respondida... obrigado pelos pontos de observação.

Answer (score 2):

Fora a opção de colocar a mensagem num TextView, você também pode usar um "Toast"

Exemplo

```
//Toast.makeText(<Context>, <Mensagem>, <Duração>).show();

Toast.makeText(this, "this is my Toast message!!! =)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Contexto da aplicação, se for em uma activity pode usar `this`, fragment pode usar o `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`

Mensagem é auto explicativa, é o texto que você quer mostrar

Duração é o tempo que a mensagem ficará na tela, existem duas constantes com tempos fixos que você pode usar, se quiser pode colocar o tempo em milissegundos

```
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT // Equivale a 2 segundos
Toast.LENGTH_LONG // Equivale a 3.5 segundos
```